# Why is NULL represented as Lambda in CWEB?

Tags: cweb

When I use `NULL` in a CWEB document, it is typeset as Λ (`\Lambda`) in the `cweave` output.
Indeed, I see `\let\NULL=\Lambda` in `cwebmac.tex`.
Why is this the default?

I was very puzzled when I first looked at the symbol--I realized that it meant `NULL` only because of the context, not by the symbol itself.

While I'm not really sure whether this question is good fit here, only results I could find on google with "NULL Lambda CWEB" was about AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knuth uses the convention that `\Lambda` stands for the null link
(nil) in his series of books *The Art of Computer Programming*. In
Volume 1, section 2.1 (the introduction of chapter 2 "Information
Structures"), page 234, he writes:

> ...; *we use the capital Greek letter Lambda to denote the null link*,
> the link to no node.

Thus, he uses this convention since the 1960s.